# How should I use stream.cast instead of typed?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: the problem]

so i'm getting the error shown in the image and my question is: How should I use stream.cast in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to change this :

```
var stream  = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
```

To this :

```
var stream  = new http.ByteStream(_image.openRead());
stream.cast();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
var stream = http.ByteStream(image.openRead())..cast();
  var length = await image.length();
  var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('image', stream, length,
      filename: basename(image.path));
  requestBody.files.add(multipartFile);
```

Comment: Is it the same using this?  
var stream = new http.ByteStream(Stream.castFrom(image.openRead()));

Comment: Hopefully same.